# Replace special character "-" with 0 integer value

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I am traversing an excel sheet using openpyxl() and copying over the contents to another excel.

```
import openpyxl

NEW_EXCEL_FILE = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook1.xlsx')
NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS = NEW_EXCEL_FILE.active
SHEET = NEW_EXCEL_FILE.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
for i,row in enumerate(SHEET.iter_rows()):
   for j,col in enumerate(row):
      col.value = col.value.replace("-", 0)
      NEW_FILE_SHEET.cell(row=i+1,column=j+1).value = col.value
      
NEW_EXCEL_FILE.save('workbook1.xlsx')
```

I need to replace the cell contents which has "-" to 0.
when i tried using **col.value.replace("-", 0)**, it is not accepting int value.

I am getting the below exception,
**TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int**

please help.

Thanks,

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not accepting int value." ? do you get an exception?

Comment: use `str(0)` inside `col.value.replace("-", 0)`, should be  `col.value.replace("-", str(0))`, or just  `col.value.replace("-", "0")`

Comment: @Scarface, this would make the value as string right? is there a way to get int values there ?

Comment: replace method works on strings, so it replace  substring  '`-'` in the text  with `'0'`

Comment: If you have a string like `foo-bar`, what would it mean to replace the `-` with an int value?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the entire cell with the number `0`? That would be `if col.value == "-": col.value = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using  `.cell(row=i, column=j).value` and for loop. So you can try this:

```
import openpyxl

NEW_EXCEL_FILE = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="workbook1.xlsx")
NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS = NEW_EXCEL_FILE.active
num_columns = NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS.max_column
num_row = NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS.max_row
for i in range(1, num_row+1):
    for j in range(1, num_columns+1):
        if NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS.cell(row=i, column=j).value == "-":
            NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS.cell(row=i, column=j).value = 0

NEW_EXCEL_FILE.save(filename="workbook1.xlsx")
```